# How to read JSON that has values in parenthesis with data type?

Tags: python, json

I have JSON file built like the following:

```
"key" : DataType("value")
```

Example -

```
[
{
"timestamp" : ISODate("2022-03-10T13:50:51.688Z"),
"some_field" : ObjectId("value"),
"normal_key" : "normal_value"
},
{
"different_field" : "just_value"
"key" : "value"
}
]
```

I can't seem to find a way to read it since as soon as I encounter the datatype I get an error:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line x column y (char z)
```

which is the location of the first dtype.

Any structured way I could handle this?

Comment: you need to write custom decoder to decode these types. Can you share what other types can be there besides ISODate, ObjectId ?

Comment: That's not valid JSON.

Comment: It's not valid JSON. Intrigued to know how you constructed the "JSON" file

Comment: `pyyaml` provides a way to do something like what you expect, though with different syntax. As YAML is a superset of JSON, you might want to look into using that instead if you are the one generating the JSON. (If someone else is generating it, tell them to stop generating invalid JSON.)

Comment: While there *are* ways of converting non-standard data-types into JSON format in such a way that would allow them to be reconstructed later, that has not been do in like that with the data you have (which looks like a Python dictionary).

Comment: @martineau and with  a python dict, is it possible to convert to DF somehow?

Comment: @LancelotduLac might be so, but I have received it like that and need to work on that as is, and eventually preferably convert it into a DF so that I could analyze the data

Comment: @DeepakTripathi Those 2 are the only types. The rest of the entries are more common structure (some are nested)

Comment: would running line by line over the file, replacing datatypes and the subsequent parenthesis (mainly for isodate) with the translated format, and then loading it as JSON could work?

Comment: Yes, I believe there is, unfortunately I'm no Pandas expert.

Comment: I found a solution - read the file, assign it to a string, replace the extra substrings, reading to DF. however since I received a downvote, I will remove the question.

Comment: @HermanK No need to remove the question. If you could show how you overcame this it would be very helpful to anyone with a similar problem

Comment: @LancelotduLac well, just reading as a string and replacing datatypes with empty strings and then just changing data types inside the dataframe solved the issue. I thought there is a way of handling data type specifications during file reading, so I didn't want to resort to such a "silly" solution. So I'm not sure if this question add real value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While in my question I was wondering if there is a JSON like way I'm not aware of to handle data types specifications inside the file itself, I realized that string handling might need to be done.

So eventually all I did was to replace the unnecessary substrings with empty strings and later handled the data types in pandas dataframe itself.

```
with open(path) as f:
    json_data = f.read()

json_data = json_data.replace( 'ISODate(','')
json_data = json_data.replace( 'ObjectId(','')
json_data = json_data.replace( ')','')
print(json_data)

df = pd.read_json(json_data, orient ='records')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you have custom data like this you can simple create temporary class as a workaround like this:

```
class TmpClass:
    def __call__(self, val):
        return str(val)
ISODate = TmpClass()
ObjectId = TmpClass()
    

a = [{
"timestamp" : ISODate("2022-03-10T13:50:51.688Z"),
"some_field" : ObjectId("value"),
"normal_key" : "normal_value"
},
{
"different_field" : "just_value",
"key" : "value"
}
]
print(a)
```

Also if you want custom logic for data types then you can separately implement the two classes with their `__call__` method and that will change your data accordingly. I have just changed them to string.

Answer (score -1):

You can use python's `json` library.

Let `s1` be an object.

```
jsonstr1 = json.dumps(s1.__dict__)  # <-- serialize the class to a JSON string.
```

Put the JSON string into the dictionary in place of the object.

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question

Comment: @BenjaminLi: The OP is trying to *read* "JSON" data in the format shown in their question, not create it. Besides that, not all Python objects have a `__dict__`.